# Do quasi-coherent sheaves form a reflective subcategory?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, abelian-categories, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $X = $ Spec $A$ be an affine scheme.
I know that there is an inclusion of categories from $A$-modules to sheaves of $\mathcal O_X$-modules on $X$, which is exact and fully faithful.

It seems to me that by Lemma 17.10.5./(4) of the stacks project
(https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BH), this inclusion functor has a right adjoint (the global section functor), hence $A$-modules form a reflective subcategory. The image of the inclusion functor is precisely the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$.

My question is: does this generalize to arbitrary (non-affine) schemes? This would immediately give a nice proof that quasi-coherent sheaves on any scheme form an Abelian category.

Comment: Note that also in your example, you have a coreflective subcategory, not a reflective one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The category of quasicoherent sheaves is actually a **co**reflective subcategory of the category of all sheaves of modules on the scheme.

[See the stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/077P).

Comment: Dear Lukas. Indeed, my example gives a coreflective subcategory. I have no idea why I thought it was reflective. Thank you for the link!